# Report Viewer (Signo Interrogacion en paginacion)

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Buenos dias,

Tengo un problema con mi report viewer, la parte de la paginacion (Numero de paginas que tiene el reporte)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparece ese signo de interrogacion, como podria quitarlo?

Tengo en mi pagina aspx el siguiente codigo

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportView" runat="server" Width="920px" BackColor="#FFFFFF"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esa interrogación significa que el numero de páginas no es real, sino una estimación, para aumentar el rendimiento del control.

Si quieres cambiar este comportamiento, tienes que modificar la propiedad [PageCountMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.pagecountmode.aspx), pasando de `Estimate` (por defecto) a `Actual`.

Comment: Perfecto, era eso! Muchas Gracias!